# Erased disc incorrectly now I have "Apple ssd ap0128J Media" instead of Macintosh HD and broken software

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, ssd

I was preparing my laptop for a sell and booted into recovery mode. I then went into disk utility, selected my Macintosh HD and erased it. When I rebooted I got stuck on a screen with a "prohibited" sign and couldn't do anything.

I restarted my mac holding down `cmd + r` and got to a screen with spinning globe where I had to select my network. It then proceeded into recovery mode after a while where I now have

`Apple ssd ap0128J Media` and osx disks as opposed to common `Macintosh HD`.
I clicked on apple ssd disc and proceeded to erase it. Selected name as `Macintosh HD`, type as `mac os extended journaled` and `guid partition map`.

I now have `Apple ssd ap0128J Media` and underneath it (nested) `Macintosh HD`.

I'm not sure about where I should go from here to re-install osx correctly? Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When you choose to Reinstall macOS you should be offered a list of disks for the installation to take place on. This is where you should see "Macintosh HD" which you're seeing in Disk Utility (as a partition). Do you see this option?